# In Linux, are there any plug-ins to let me do `<Win>`+`<Num>` style app switching (like Windows 7's superbar)?

Tags: linux, gnome, kde, window-manager

Using Windows 7's superbar, I can select/launch the 2nd application group by `<Win>`+`<2>`. We have [DockbarX](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/DockbarX?content=101604) in GNOME, which is nice (grouping the windows like Windows 7), but it doesn't enable the `<Win>`+`<2>` style keybaord shortcuts.

Any suggestions?

This is not restricted to making Linux like Windows. But I just find the `<Win>`+`<2>` style shortcut very useful. Are there similar ways in Linux to quickly switch between specific apps without pressing `<Alt>`+`<Tab>` many many times?

Answer (score 0):

I'm planning on adding something like that to the next version of DockbarX. It will probably be <kbd>super</kbd>+s (or something similar) and then the number instead of <kbd>super</kbd>+number straight away, because that is simpler to implement.

Oh, and Unity is also implementing this (<kbd>super</kbd>+number).